# Do i have to include the html tag?

Tags: html

I know this might sound like a stupid question, but i have a .php file in which I'm using html tags combined with php code. Nothing is included withing the `<html>` tag and yet all the html elements seem to be displayed just fine. So what's the use of this tag? Does including the `<html>` tag actually make a difference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The start and end tags for the `html` element are [defined as being optional](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/global.html#edef-HTML) (and will be inserted by the parser if the context demands that the element starts or finishes). However, if you don't have a start tag for `html` then you can't put a `lang` attribute on it, and [you should include a `lang` attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/H57.html).

Comment: @JanDvorak — I'd forgotten that it specified it under the DTD extract. I was trying to avoid having to explain what `O` meant.

Comment: can the same be said for the body tag?

Comment: @DarrenSadr it is optional as well, I don't recommend omitting any of them, though.

Comment: @DarrenSadr — The [index of elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/index/elements.html) tells you which have optional (and forbidden) start / end tags.

Comment: @DarrenSadr some people like attaching classes and/or an ID to the `body`, which can't be done if you omit the tag.